# Combining two or more insert and if isset

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it was at all possible to have two or more **inserts into** and **if isset** statements that insert into the same table on the same webpage at the same time or even better within one query.

I have a university project, which is asking for 2/3 sets of information to be inserted into a single db tbl at the same time. I have tried to do 2 out of the 3 queries separately but i am receiving ***"Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'"***, which makes sense as my name column in the db is unique.

The 2/3 sets of information are different from one and other, 1 set is inputted information, such as name, address etc. The other two sets are based on checkbox and radio button inputs e.g if checkbox is checked insert 1 into the DB, if it is unchecked insert 2.

Assuming the best practice is to combine the queries into one query, I have no idea how to do that. Especially as they are two different input types. Very new! so any help would be appreciated. cheers!

**INSERT into on duplicate- (text data)**

```
  $adm_Franchise = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['Franchise']);


    if (isset($_POST['Save-details'])) {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['ID']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
        $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['lname']);


    $insert = "INSERT INTO Details
  ( ID , name , lname ) 
  VALUES ( ? , ?,?) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE ID = ?
  , name               = ?
  , lname       = ?";


        $ce = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert);

       //$ce = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ce, 'ississ', $id, $name, $lname,$id, $name, $lname );

        /* execute query */
        $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($ce);

        if ($execute) {
            echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
```

**$_POST variables HTML**

As requested:

```
<form id="myform " class="Form" method="POST" action="Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=<?php echo $_GET['Franchise']; ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

   <div class="group1">
       <div class="field">
               <fieldset>

                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placement="Customer Name" required>
                </div><br>

                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" placement="Customer Last Name" required>

       </fieldset>
```

**Checkbox query**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="saleItem" value="1" <?php echo (isset($_GET['saleItem']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?> />

 $is_checked = (isset($_GET['saleItem']) ? '1' : '2');

 $sql=mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO Details (active) VALUES ('" . $is_checked . "')"); 

 if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error($dbc));
   }
   mysqli_close($dbc);
```

**DB**

```
CREATE TABLE `Details` (
`ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`active` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`Rname`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=210 DEFAULT CHARSET=outfit
```

Comment: How are your sets linked together i.e. How do you know if the values from the checkboxes belong to one particular set of inputted informations? Do they belong to the same form?

Comment: @Osuwariboy  i am using fieldsets to group sets of information together

Comment: Could you include what's in the $_POST variable, it would help to figuring out how to insert the data you're receiving if we know how it's organized. You can do `print_r($_POST)` to do that

Comment: @Osuwariboy okay give me 2 minutes

Comment: You are aware you can put checkboxes in the same form as text boxes, right?

Comment: @Osuwariboy yeah, but because i was trying at first to submit them separating thats why. I thought trying to submit them together would be messy. But it seems like the only way

Comment: It's actually the best way to go... and one thing you should know is that if a checkbox is not checked, browsers will not submit them so they won't exist in the $_POST. It's something you can easily take advantage of when you receive the data thanks to the isset() function.

Comment: @Osuwariboy yeah very true. But how would i make them into one query, because two if issets are needed

Comment: Where does your $id come from? Btw, every user can overwrite all other userdata if you use it from a post-variable! What do you mean by "if checkbox is checked insert 1 into the DB, if it is unchecked insert 2." I guess you mean "update", so maybe "update Details set active = ? where id = ?;" (then bind with $is_checked and $id). What is Rname in your table? Why is name unique? Why put the registration information in the same table as the answers (or is it really just 1 value "active"?)? Unfortunatetly there is really a lot wrong or missing here.

Comment: @Solarflare the checkbox query above successfully inserts 1 into the DB when the checkbox is checked and if it is unchecked it inserts 2 into the DB. I just want to insert both the name, lname and checkbox data into the db all at once. I have another query before this query where the id is defined. The name and ID are unique together, because i am going to call the customer info and active in another query to get the info, it is needed to long to explain why

Answer (score 0):

Given my limited understanding of your problem, here's what I propose. First, you have one page with the form containing all your controls.

```
<form id="myform " class="Form" method="POST" action="Main_Franchise_Details.php?Franchise=<?php echo $_GET['Franchise']; ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placement="Customer Name" required><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" placement="Customer Last Name" required>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" placement="Customer Last Name" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="otherStatus" name="otherStatus" value="1">
</form>
```

Above is a very simplified example. But then, when you submit the said form, you'll receive your data in the $_POST variable so here's what you can do to insert it all in one go:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['ID']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['lname']);

//first checkbox isn't set so this means we have to insert 1 into the database otherwise 
//we just insert the value
if(!isset($_POST['status']))
    $status = 1;
else
    $status = $_POST['status'];

//second checkbox isn't set so in this case we have to insert 2 into the database otherwise
//we just insert its value
if(!isset($_POST['otherStatus']))
    $otherStatus = 2;
else
    $otherStatus = $_POST['otherStatus'];

//So now we're ready so we insert into one single query

$insert = "INSERT INTO Detail (ID, lname, fname, status, otherStatus) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
$ce = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ce, 'ississ', $id, $name, $lname, $status, $otherStatus);

$execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($ce);

if ($execute) 
{
    echo "saved";
}
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. I'll update accordingly.